# Json.NET Not serializing to file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Even using an example from the [Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm), I still can't find a way to successfully serialize to a file.

Code:

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Item i = new Item
            {
                Username = "user",
                Email = "user@user.com",
                Password = "password"
            };


            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\users\user1.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i));

            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"C:\users\user1.json"))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(file, i);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Item.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I run Program.cs, it shows no errors, but the JSON does not show in the file.

Comment: You're writing to the same file twice, which makes it hard to tell which part is failing; have you tried assigning `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i)` to a variable and checking it during debugging?

Comment: Your code is working good at my computer.

Comment: Yeah users is a protected folder... And it's not going to always be c:\users for everyone.. E.g. my users folder is on p:\os\users and my temp folder is p:\temp.. and my OS is on c:\ e.g. c:\windows.  Long story short you should use environment variables, e.g. @"%homepath%\user.json" which would put it in c:\users\user1\user.json in your example "the current logged in user's user folder"

Comment: Sorry, the "users" folder was supposed to be for the database, not the system's users. I forgot that Windows contains a Users folder at the root of the C: drive. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get a an exception writing to the users folder. Changing to my home folder works fine. I suspect this is your problem.

Addtionally, you're writing the file twice. The first time is showing an example of using the SerializeObject method to get a string back which is used with WriteAllText. The second block of code is using a StreamWriter. For your purposes, both are equivalent and you only need to use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"C:\users\user1.json"))
        {
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i);
            file.WriteLine(jsonResult);
        }
```

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_2.htm

You're rewriting the method being called.